# creating tar archives using gulp

Tags: gulp, tar

I'm using gulp-tar to create a tar file... how do I add a top level folder so that when the user runs `tar -xzf myArchive.tar` it extracts into a specific folder.

here's my code:

```
gulp.task('prod', ['min', 'gittag'], function() {

  //copy all files under /server into a zip file
    gulp.src('../server/**/*')
    .pipe(tar('xoserver' + '-'+ gittag +'.tar'))
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../prod'));
});
```

The above creates a `tar.zip` file all right, but I have to be careful to add a `-C <folder>` while extracting, else the files get extracted to the current folder.

[edited]

What I'm trying to do here is generate a tarball of the format `xoserver-alpha-d414ddf.tar.gz` which, when extracted with a `tar xvf` will create a folder `xoserver-alpha-d414ddf` and unpack all the files under it. Essentially I am trying to add new folder name above my packed files.
If I add a `base` option, the folder extracted to is just `server`

[ANSWER]

Thanks to ddprrt for a good answer. I am reproducing the final code in case someone else wants to use a similar strategy of embedding the git tag into the name of the tarball for distribution/testing.

```
gulp.task('gittag', function(cb) {   // generate the git tag 
    git.exec({args : 'branch -v'}, function (err, stdout) {
      var lines = stdout.split('\n');
      for (var l in lines) {
        if (lines[l][0] == '*') {
          var words = lines[l].split(/\s+/);
          gittag = words[1]+ '-' + words[2];
          console.log('Gittag is %s', gittag);
          break;
        }
      }
      cb();
    });
});

gulp.task('min', ['runbmin', 'template', 'vendor']); // generate min files

gulp.task('prod', ['min', 'gittag'], function() { // create tarball
  //copy all files under /server into a zip file
    return gulp.src('../server/**/*')
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        path.dirname = 'server-' + gittag + '/' + path.dirname;
    }))
    .pipe(tar('xoserver-'+gittag+'.tar'))
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../prod'));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `base` option is for.

```
gulp.task('prod', ['min', 'gittag'], function() {
    return gulp.src('../server/**/*', { base: '../server/' })
        .pipe(tar('xoserver' + '-'+ gittag +'.tar'))
        .pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../prod'));
});
```

With it you can tell gulp which paths to include when dealing with the globs you receive.

Btw. Don't forget to return streams or call the done callback in your task. Helps gulp orchestrating your build pipeline

As for the second question, you can use [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) task to change the directory where your virtual files are located. Would be something like

```
.pipe(rename(function(path) {
     path.dirname = 'whatever/' + path.dirname
}));
```

Comment: Thanks.. that only solves part of the problem, though. I have edited the question to clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: alright! See my update... I guess that might help :-)

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm. I am updating my question with the final gulp code I am using... just in case anyone is interested